# Discord js creating discord category

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make a category on discord server using ***Discord Bot*** but I couldn't find the method or something on internet. Also I looked the "discord.js.org". Then I thought that isn't there any possibility to do that. So is there any way to make a category on discord servers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `.createChannel` method and then enter „category“ as type of the channel

```
<guild>.createChannel("NAME OF THE CHANNEL", "category")
```

Answer (score 6):

discordjs v13 needs GUILD_CATEGORY instead of just "category"

```
message.guild.channels.create("Name", { type: "GUILD_CATEGORY" });
```

Answer (score 4):

I would advice the usage of a promise as it adds a lot of functionality and safety to your code

```
guild.createChannel('new-category', {
  type: 'category',
  permissionsOverwrites: [{
    id: guild.id,
    deny: ['MANAGE_MESSAGES'],
    allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES']
  }]
})
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

This allows you to create the channel with permissions and actually handle any errors like the channel already existing or your bot not being able to create said channel cause of its permissions assigned.

This is the proper way to do this.

Example to create channel

```
guild.createChannel('new-general', { type: 'text' })
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 2):

v12:

```js
message.guild.channels.create('Category', { type: 'category' });
```

Comment: thats not up to date

Answer (score 0):

I have made a command code for you to use. Modify it and use it.

```
if(message.content === `${prefix}create-channel`) {
  message.guild.createChannel('name', {
    //Channel type (text || voice || category)
    type: 'text', 
    permissionsOverwrites: [{
      id: guild.id,
      deny: [],
      allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES']
    }]
  })
  .catch(console.error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

discordjs v14 needs `ChannelType.GuildCategory` and the name in the `options`

```js
message.guild.channels.create({ name: "Name", type: ChannelType.GuildCategory });
```

Comment: ChannelType imported from where?

Comment: @Nikos from discordjs, like so `import { ChannelType } from 'discord.js';`